# Mutate lead variables

Tags: julia

This is my code:

```
data = @pipe data |> sort(_, :year) |> groupby(_,:id) |> 
 transform(_, :a1 => (x -> lead(x,1) .- x ) => :b1; ungroup = false) |>
 transform(_, :a2 => (x -> lead(x,2) .- x ) => :b2; ungroup = false) |>
 transform(_, :a3 => (x -> lead(x,3) .- x ) => :b3, ungroup = false) |>
 transform(_, :a4 => (x -> lead(x,4) .- x ) => :b4, ungroup = false) |>
 transform(_, :a5 => (x -> lead(x,5) .- x ) => :b5)
```

Is this the most efficient way to mutate lead variables on a very large dataset?

`data` is a DataFrame with columns `a1`, ..., `:a5`, and I want to have columns `b1` , ..., `:b5` where `bi = lead(ai, i)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question about "most efficient" has many dimensions, but I assume you want to avoid as much allocations as possible, in this case do the following:

```
@pipe data |>
      sort!(_, :year) |>
      groupby(_,:id) |> 
      transform!(_, [Symbol(:a, i) => (x -> lead(x, i) .- x ) => Symbol(:b, i) for i in 1:5])
```

in this way you will update your `data` data frame in-place minimizing copying (your solution copies a lot).

Comment: Great, I meant to lessen the allocation as much as possible.